# Need to get owner's name of the first suitcase unloaded

Tags: ruby

I would like to know what i need to do to make the program below give me the owner's name of the first suitcase unloaded, when the method `take_from_plane` is called on a `CargoHold` object. I created a `say_owner_name` method in `Suitcase` class, but don't know how to make the connection between `Suitcase` and `CargoHold`, in this context.

```
module Stacklike
  def stack
    @stack ||= []
  end
  def add_to_stack(obj)
    stack.push(obj)
  end
  def take_from_stack
    stack.pop
  end
end

class Suitcase 
  include Stacklike
  attr_accessor :name
  def initialize(person)
    self.name = person
    puts "#{person}'s suitcase"
  end
  def say_owner_name
    print name
  end
end

class CargoHold 
  include Stacklike
  def load_and_report(obj)
    print "Loading..."
    puts obj.object_id
    add_to_stack(obj)
  end
  def take_from_plane
    take_from_stack
  end
end

ch = CargoHold.new
s1 = Suitcase.new("Caio")
s2 = Suitcase.new("John")
s3 = Suitcase.new("Jack")

ch.load_and_report(s1)
ch.load_and_report(s2)
ch.load_and_report(s3)

first_unload = ch.take_from_plane
puts "The first suitcase to be unloaded is #{first_unload.object_id}."
```

Comment: Everything looks correct - if you just `puts firstunload.say_owner_name` you should get `"Jack"`.

Comment: Ah, but instead of only `print name` in `say_owner_name`, you might also want to return it. `def say_owner_name; print name; name; end`

Comment: Oh wait - I read your question again - you want to return the person's name at the moment it is removed, such as in the `take_from_plane()` method?

Comment: At first, not necessarily. But now that you mention it, how can i do it? Oh, and many thanks for the support by the way :)

Comment: I believe @MichaelBerkowski is correct: `puts firstunload.say_owner_name => "Jack"`. Note that there is no need for `include Stacklike` in class `CargoHold` or the reference to `object_id`. Also, the name `firstunload` is a bit of a misnomer, as it applies to every bag removed.  Apply it twice more: `ch.take_from_plane.say_owner_name #=> "John",
ch.take_from_plane.say_owner_name #=> "Caio"`

Comment: Just tested it. You're right. I called firstunload.say_owner_name and it works. But how? How can i call a Suitcase method on a CargoHold object? As far as i can see, they are not connected in any way...

Comment: The `CargoHold` object is saving `Suitcase` objects on its stack, so `take_from_stack` returns a `Suitcase` object.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Please post the comment as an answer, as it appears to have helped OP.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski please post your comment as an answer.